# How can I zip file with a flattened directory structure using Zipfile in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using the `ZipFile` package to zip file in Python. Here's my code:

```
archive = zipfile.ZipFile(join(settings.ARCHIVES_DIR, 'test.zip'), "a")

for pdffile in glob.glob(join(settings.IBILLING_DIR, '*.pdf')):
    archive.write(pdffile)

archive.close()
```

The issue I'm facing is that the ZIP file that is created, contains a directory structure. The files that are added are added with the full the path which means that the user that extracts the archive, will also end up getting a directory structure. I'd like to the add files to the ZIP but without any directory structure.

How can I do this? I didn't find this information in the docs.

Thanks

Comment: try using `os.walk`, rather than glob?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First add

```
import os
```

then modify the `archive.write` line to be:

```
archive.write(pdffile, os.path.basename(pdffile))
```

This specifies that each pdf should be written into the zip file with a path equivalent to only the filename portion of the path from which you are reading it (by specifying the [arcname parameter for the `write()` call](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write)).

Note, however, that this means that if you have two PDF files with the same name in different directories, one will overwrite the other.