# python - archive file without full path

Tags: python

I have the following script -

```
import os
import stat
import zipfile
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import logging

logfile = 'D:\\logfiles\\MasterLogsArchive\\archive.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)

try:
    import zlib
    compression = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
except:
    compression = zipfile.ZIP_STORED

modes = { zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED: 'deflated',
          zipfile.ZIP_STORED:   'stored',
          }

def modified_date(filename):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(os.stat(filename)[stat.ST_MTIME])

def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

move_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes = 2)
src = "D:\\program files (x86)\\TIDAL\\Scheduler\\Master\\log"


for filename in os.listdir(src):
    full_filename = os.path.join(src, filename)
    scheduler = os.path.join(src, 'scheduler.out')

    if modified_date(full_filename) < move_date and filename.startswith('Master'):
        filedate = find_between(filename, '-', '.')[:-7]
        date = filedate[:-2]
        year = filedate[:-6]
        month = filedate[4:-4]
        day = filedate[6:-2]
        hour = filedate[8:]
        dest = "D:\\logfiles\\MasterLogsArchive\\" + date 
        if not os.path.exists(dest):
            os.makedirs(dest)
        zf = dest + '\\' + 'Master%s%s%s-%s.zip' % (year, month, day, hour)

        ## add Master Logs
        if (os.path.isfile(full_filename)):
            if (os.path.isfile(zf)):
                try:
                    logging.info('%s is archived' % full_filename)
                    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zf, mode='a')
                    zip.write(full_filename, compress_type=compression)
                    os.remove(full_filename)
                finally:
                    zip.close()
            else:
                try:
                    logging.info('%s is archived' % full_filename)
                    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(dest + '\\' + 'Master%s%s%s-%s.zip' % (year, month, day, hour), mode='w')
                    zip.write(full_filename, compress_type=compression)
                    os.remove(full_filename)
                finally:
                    zip.close()
```

The problem I'm having is that in compression it's doing the full path which I don't want.  I only want the file in the zip.  If I change the zip.write to do 'filename' instead of 'full_filename' it then complains it can't find the file.

So how do I get the write to know what folder to grab the file out of?

Answer (score 0):

The actual write needs to be changed to the following -

```
zip.write(full_filename, os.path.basename(full_filename), compress_type=compression)
```

Got the answer from here -

[How can I zip file with a flattened directory structure using Zipfile in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777222/how-can-i-zip-file-with-a-flattened-directory-structure-when-zipping-file-using#12777267)